# PHP: Can I remove &#8234; #&lrm; from string

Tags: php, expression, non-ascii-characters

I need to remove `&#8234;#&lrm;` from string. I found this method:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```

It doesn't work for the Thai language. I want to remove like this:

from

```
&#8234;#&lrm;Apple&#8236; &#8234;#&lrm;ผลไม้&#8236;
```

to

```
#Apple #ผลไม้
```

Comment: What is your complete $string ?

Comment: $string = ‪'#‎apple ‪#ผลไม้';  I copy this text from hashtag facebook.

Comment: why arent you use `str_replace` and passing &#8234;#&lrm; ?

Comment: I have tried, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not understand why `str_replace()` did not work for you. This will do the job:

```
function cleanString($string) {
    $search = array('&#8234;', '&lrm;', '&#8236;');
    $replace = array('', '', '');

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}
$string = '&#8234;#&lrm;Apple&#8236; &#8234;#&lrm;ผลไม้&#8236;';

echo $string . "\n";
echo cleanString($string) . "\n";
```

Output is:

```
&#8234;#&lrm;Apple&#8236; &#8234;#&lrm;ผลไม้&#8236;
#Apple #ผลไม้
```

Working example can be found at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bbdbdf0758e5ea06faf32281021ae859b6d75a51